# Installed packages: what repository are they from?

Tags: apt, ppa

How can I determine which repository is being used for an installed packages? I have a few custom PPA repositories, and I'm concerned on one system whether the installed package is from one PPA or the other.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you install synaptic (sudo apt-get install synaptic), you can use it to view the sources of packages:

[image: Synaptic]